# You provided 'function catchErrorOperatorFunction(source) where a stream was expected

Tags: angular

I have an error in my application, it doesn't do anything so far, but it bothers me. I'm using angular 9 already. My application html is empty at momment because i need to fix these bugs first.

See the error image

[image: error message]

There is another error when my service is called. Please, take a look at that

I have no idea what could be. Anyway, i have a stackblitz to show mmy application.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lunqxs

Comment: I don't see any errors. Which file are you referring to?

Comment: error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class

Comment: Does this error appear in the stackblitz link you provided?

Comment: no, this error just appears in my VS code console

Comment: Hmm, can't really say then coz we can't reproduce it.

Comment: Remove node_modules and run npm i

Comment: but there is an error in the stackblitz link that appears in console at beginning

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the one in the image you pasted.

Comment: I know, but i said in message that i have 2 errors

Answer (score 1):

Update your `hero.service.ts` with this code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return throwError(error);
  }

  public get(): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.http.get<any>('viacep.com.br/ws/09890430/json/').pipe(
      map((response: any) => response),
      catchError(catchError(this.handleError))
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing import of `HttpClient` or `HttpClientModule` from `app.module.ts`